# AlarmManager won't start service

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager

I just followed the exact code in API Demo, but my service just won't start after I set the AlarmManager.

so my service is

```
public class CourseWatcherRefreshService extends Service {

    private CourseDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private CourseWatcher watcher;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Watcher Refresh Service starts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mDbHelper = new CourseDbAdapter(this);
        mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mDbHelper.open();
        Thread thread = new Thread(null, mTast, "CourseWatcherRefreshService");
        thread.start();
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mDbHelper.close();
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    Runnable mTast = new Runnable() {
        // some work
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new Binder() {
        @Override
        protected boolean onTransact(int code, Parcel data, Parcel reply, int flags)
                throws RemoteException {
            return super.onTransact(code, data, reply, flags);
        }
    };

}
```

Also in my AndroidManifest.xml, I put such code

```
<service
    android:name=".CourseWatcherRefreshService"
    android:process=":remote" >
</service>
```

And I use such code to toggle the AlarmManager

```
PendingIntent refreshIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(NaviScreen.this, 0, new Intent(NaviScreen.this, CourseWatcherRefreshService.class), 0);
long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,firstTime, 30*1000, refreshIntent);
```

And the code above is almost the same with the AlartService example in API Demo, but my code won't work, I can't see any sign of my service starts to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `getActivity` when you should be using `getService`. So change the PendingIntent line to

```
PendingIntent refreshIntent = PendingIntent.getService(NaviScreen.this, 0, new Intent(NaviScreen.this, CourseWatcherRefreshService.class), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Intent updateIntent = new Intent() 
updateIntent.setClass(NaviScreen.this, CourseWatcherRefreshService.class) 
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, updateIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Opps! sorry I didn't know that Craigy already had answered this !